# Template Engine in NodeJS & BackboneJS

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, template-engine

currently i am playing around with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) (+ [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com)) and [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/).
The Backbone pages told me (including the [Todo Example](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html)) that it's better to use a template engine such as [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) or [MustacheJS](http://mustache.github.com/). But i am already using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com) which comes with ExpressJS.

Are **Front-End** (e.g. Mustache) and **Back-End** (e.g. Jade) template engines completely different or is it possible to use one for both ?

Or did I not understand something right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same template engine for both frontend and backend (we are using it in a project for both sides).  Also with care, its easy to switch some forms across as well. To compile jade to client, see

- https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#browser-support

very easily this could be incorporated as grunt task, i have put the code in

- https://gist.github.com/2877717

Answer (score 0):

Jade works on the front and back-end. You still need to create client-side and server-side templates though.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, if you are already are already using Node.js and Express.js, there is little need to do front-end templating, since you can already control everything server-side. Mixing both is usually unnecessary and very tricky.

As an aside, I would recommend using [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) for back-end templating.

EDIT: Apologies, I think I skirted the complexity of the question a bit. Yes, you can definitely use both, and in the cases of large complex data sets you definitely *should* use at least a front-end templating engine like Mustache. If you are just getting started with ExpressJS, it's best to stick with just a back-end templating engine like Jade or EJS until you are more comfortable with how back-end templating works—then move to using both if you see it fit.

Thanks to Pickels for calling me out on that!

Comment: You need to explain yourself because what you said is wrong. Node.js or Express.js doesn't remove the need for client-side templates. If I want to render complex data on the client it's still preferable to use a template engine that's also on the client.